# HTML CSS hover change two element

Tags: html, css

I need to show two animations on hovering the menu,

1. Highlight the menu text with an underline.
2. Show another sub-menu.

Below are the CSS and HTML, wherein below code the Menu highlighting is working but the submenu show is not working.

```css
.menuText {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menuText:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.menuText:hover:after {
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
}

.menuText:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.menuText:active {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .2);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Catamaran;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity .9s ease-in;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.menuText:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:100vh; background-image: url('./images/10.png');">

  <!-- --------------------- Top Menu ----------------------------------------- -->
  <div class="navBar">
  
    <a class="menuText"> HOME</a>
    <a id="buildingMenuID" class="menuText"> BUS</a>

    <div>

      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>

      <!-- --------------------- ------------------------------------------------- -->


      <div>
```

What could be the problem, basically I have to show submenu when the user moves the mouse over the main menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.dropdown-content` is not a descendant of `.menuText` so your selector `.menuText:hover .dropdown-content` will do nothing.

`.dropdown-content` is a descendant of a `div` which is in turn a sibling of `.menuText`.

The selector you are looking for would be `.menuText:hover ~ div > .dropdown-content` (see example below).

However, because of the way your HTML is structured, the submenu will display when *any* menu item is hovered. I would suggest restructuring your HTML so that the submenus are descendants of the menu items. Similar to the code in this question: [Keep parent menu item highlighted after hovering over submenu (HTML/CSS/Jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802823/keep-parent-menu-item-highlighted-after-hovering-over-submenu-html-css-jquery)

```css
.menuText {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menuText:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.menuText:hover:after {
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
}

.menuText:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.menuText:active {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .2);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Catamaran;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity .9s ease-in;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.menuText:hover ~ div > .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:100vh; background-image: url('./images/10.png');">

  <!-- --------------------- Top Menu ----------------------------------------- -->
  <div class="navBar">
    <i class="material-icons" style="  font-size:22px;color:#ccc">home</i>
    <a class="menuText"> HOME</a>

    <i class="material-icons" style="  font-size:22px;color:#ccc">business</i>
    <a id="buildingMenuID" class="menuText"> BUS</a>

    <div>

      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>

      <!-- --------------------- ------------------------------------------------- -->


      <div>
```